# Why is this bare minimum Angular with Lexical.dev setup not working?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lexicaljs

I was following the https://lexical.dev/docs/getting-started/quick-start

It seem straightforward.

```js
import { createEditor } from 'lexical';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div contenteditable="true" #editable></div>
  `,
})
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  private editor = createEditor();

  @ViewChild('editable') editable?: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const el = this.editable?.nativeElement;
    if (el) {
      this.editor.setRootElement(el);
      console.log('set');
    } else console.log('nop');
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hkyhci?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

And I'm getting nothing and no errors. What am I missing here?

Comment: what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I was expecting to see some editor ui like this: https://playground.lexical.dev/

Comment: No UI shows up even in a [vanilla js project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3yv7zy?file=index.html,index.js).  Maybe lexical doesn't include the UI, but only the underlying logic to manipulate the rich text document?

Comment: @BizzyBob yes, it's so sad that one of the best libraries out there for rich text editing has an excuse of a documentation for non-react users, yet it claims to have a vanillaJS version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into it, Lexical is a complex beast of a WYSIWYG, that requires its own plugins to work.

Just to get basic text entry, you need to install a separate module:

```
import { registerPlainText } from '@lexical/plain-text';
```

and then alter your example code like so:

```
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  editor: LexicalEditor = createEditor();

  @ViewChild('editable') editable?: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.editable) {
      this.editor.setRootElement(this.editable.nativeElement);
      registerPlainText(this.editor);
    }
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-z7qv1j?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Side note, Lexical is maintained by Meta and all examples are provided in ReactJs. It is designed to work with any UI framework; however, it requires quite a lot of code just to get a basic setup running if you are not using ReactJs.

I would suggest using a different WYSIWYG in angular like [Quill](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill) which is much easier to get started with and can be customized to an extent.

However, be warned that this is wrapper around QuillJs V1 which has a few issues but works quite well for basic uses. V2 fixes/improves a lot of issues and is in the final stages of being released after being stopped for something like a year as the original maintainer started developing the project privately for his own company, pretty much abandoning the project.